# How to detect if Facebook app is logged in by users on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am developing an app with a page displaying the fb native ad by Facebook audience network SDK (4.x), and the visibility of the page entry button is depended on whether Facebook app is logged in or not.

I've used

```
SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook)
```

on iOS 9 but it seems return true even logged out from Facebook app.

I found  after killing the app and relaunch again, it would return the correct value.

Is there any way to detect if users exactly logged in from Facebook app?

Or am I misusing the isAvailableForServiceType API?